# SysLink control - set property Visible in C++ code

Tags: mfc, controls, visible

I have a SysLink Control with ID of "IDC_SYSLINK", and the Visible is set to false as default. Based on some logic, it will then be set to True from the C++ code.

In the class CMFCSomeDlg, I defined a member variable m_SysLink of type CLinkCtrl, and link with IDC_SYSLINK by doing the following,

```
void CMFCSomeDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_SYSLINK, m_SysLink);
}
```

I wonder how can I use m_SysLink to dynamically set the Visible property of SysLink control?

Comment: I just figured this out myself.

Use m_SysLink.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW) will do the job.

Comment: Please post your answer as an answer (and not as a comment) and accept it.